# pointer return type from a function in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I was trying to run this program where an iterator is passed through a method. The method should increase value by plus one and to return it. I get error : C:\C++ programe file\test2\main.cpp|23|error message:

cannot convert 'std::list::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator}' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'int* getValue(int*)'|

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int* getValue(int*);

int main ()
{
    list<int>* t = new list<int>();

    for (int i=1; i<10; ++i)
    {
        t->push_back(i*10);
    }

    for (list<int>:: iterator it = t->begin(); it != t->end(); it++)
    {
        cout<< getValue(it)<< "\n"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


int* getValue(int* data)
{
    int* _t = data +1 ;

    return _t;
}
```

Anyone knows how to correct it ?

Comment: Iterators aren't (usually) pointers. A list iterator in particular isn't random access so your attempted pointer arithmetic in `getValue` would be invalid anyway.

Comment: how can I pass an iterator and do stuff with that ?

Comment: Take an `list<int>::iterator` as argument instead of `int*`.

Comment: @user2746110 You would have your parameter as a `list<int>::iterator` rather than an `int*`. After that change you should notice that there is an error in `getValue` and that there isn't an `operator+` for the iterator.

Comment: Can I write the prototype like this ?

Comment: Can I write the prototype like this ?   int* getValue(list<int>:: iterator _it);

Comment: @user2746110 you're still returning an `int*`. It's not a pointer.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do here. Do you want to modify the list? Should `getValue` return a pointer (or iterator, or value, or something) to/of the *next* element in the list? Or the value of this element plus one (or a pointer to a variable containing that number, or something)?

Comment: I don't want to modify the list itself. Only print plus one. It's an small experiment to see that I can pass an iterator to do stuff and get something as return value.

Comment: What does "print plus one" mean? Plus one to what? What output do you expect your program to have?

Comment: Hi simple@ what will the the return type ?

Comment: why don't you just print (*it)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is actually pretty spot on. Your function should probably be like this:

```
int getValue(list<int>::iterator data) // take an iterator instead of an pointer and return a int.
{
    int _t = *data +1 ; dereference data to get the value at that location.

    return _t;
}
```

In your original version you're taking an `int *` which isn't the same as a list iterator. Also you're returning a pointer instead of a int value. The dereference is there, so that you increment the value at the location denoted by the iterator and not the iterator itself (which isn't even possible for list iterators).

Also most likely you won't need to `new` your list, just use one with automatic storage duration. Change:

```
list<int>* t = new list<int>();
```

to

```
list<int> t;
```

Comment: thanks. It's running now.

Comment: @user2746110 I should probably add that `cout<< *it + 1 << "\n"<<endl;` should be considered like Pandrei suggested on a comment, since your function hardly does anything.

Comment: I know that use, only want to learn how to use function. In reality, there will be more thing in the function.